# C++ differentiation library

Tags: library, c++, math

I have a string with some expression and I want get string with derivative of this expression. For example:

```
std::string s = "x^2 - 6*x + 5";
std::string s2 = differentiate(s);
std::cout << s2;
```

output will be :

```
2 * x - 6
```

is there some C++ library which can deal with this problem?

Comment: I haven't found answer for this question but I have found better way to deal with my problem: instead of differentiate functions and evaluate them, I will use numerical differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do symbolic math in C++; differentiation is just an example of that.

While I don't have experience doing that myself, I can at least help you with a few suggestion:

- [SymbolicC++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SymbolicC%2B%2B):

  ```
  Symbolic p("p"), q("q");
  cout << df(cos(p[q]^2) - (q^2)*sin(q),q) << endl; // - 2*q*sin(q)-q^(2)*cos(q) -2*sin(p[q]^(2))*p[q]*df(p[q],q)
  cout << integrate(ln(q), q) << endl;     // q*ln(q) - q
  ```
- [ViennaMath](http://viennamath.sourceforge.net/):

  ```
  // some kind of definition of x and y as symbolic functions
  diff( x + y, x ); // returns 1
  diff( (2.0 - x) * (3.0 + y), y); // returns 2.0 - x
  ```
- [GiNaC](http://www.ginac.de/):

  ```
  symbol x("x"), y("y"), z("z");
  ex P = pow(x, 5) + pow(x, 2) + y;

  cout << P.diff(x,2) << endl;  // 20*x^3 + 2
  cout << P.diff(y) << endl;    // 1
  cout << P.diff(z) << endl;    // 0
  ```
- C or C++ bindings for [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) - which [I understand exist](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/External-Code-Interface.html), but I haven't really looked into them. Octave's symbolic math facilities obviously support [differentiation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/@sym/diff.html).